# Use annotations to set test parameters on Java

Tags: java, annotations, junit4

I'll start by saying that one of the things I really don't understand about Java is annotations.

I come from a python background so I tend to think of annotations as modifiers on methods which could do potentially anything (like decorators on python).

Now, I have a problem that, in terms of syntax, it would look very nice if could be solved using annotations, but I don't know if it can be done.

Basically, I have different versions of an API: v1, v2, v3, v4. And I have JUnit4 tests for each of those versions.

ApiV1Test.java

```
@Test
public void featureX() {
  Connection conn = new ApiConnection("v1");
  response = conn.request("x", "foo")';
  assertEquals("bar", response);
}

@Test
public void featureY() {
  Connection conn = new ApiConnection("v1");
  response = conn.request("y", "foo_y")';
  assertEquals("bar_y", response);
}
```

ApiV2Test.java

```
@Test
public void featureX() {
  Connection conn = new ApiConnection("v2");
  response = conn.request("x", "foo")';
  assertEquals("bar", response);
}

@Test
public void featureZ() {
  Connection conn = new ApiConnection("v2");
  response = conn.request("z", "foo_y")';
  assertEquals("bar_z", response);
}
```

The thing is that different versions have different features; v1 may have features X and Y, v2 may have features X and Z. And so on, each feature is available in some subset of the Apis.

So, this leads to a lot of code repetition. I would like to have just one file with all the different features and have a mechanism for saying "run this test for these versions", something like:

```
@Test
@Versions("v1", "v2")
public void featureX(String version) {
  Connection conn = new ApiConnection(version);
  response = conn.request("x", "foo")';
  assertEquals("bar", response);
}

@Test
@Versions("v1")
public void featureY(String version) {
  Connection conn = new ApiConnection(version);
  response = conn.request("y", "foo_y")';
  assertEquals("bar_y", response);
}


@Test
@Versions("v2")
public void featureZ(String version) {
  Connection conn = new ApiConnection(version);
  response = conn.request("z", "foo_z")';
  assertEquals("bar_z", response);
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Since JUnit 4, you can do that.  Look up `Categories`.

```
// In Version1.java.
public interface Version1 { /* category marker */ }

// In Version2.java.
public interface Version2 { /* category marker */ }

// Part of ApiV1Test.java
@Test
@Category({Version1.class, Version2.class})
public void featureX( String version) {
    Connection conn = new ApiConnection(version);
    response = conn.request("x", "foo")';
    assertEquals("bar", response);
}

// Part of ApiV2Test.java
@Test
@Category(Version2.class)
public void featureZ(String version) {
    Connection conn = new ApiConnection(version);
    response = conn.request("z", "foo_z")';
    assertEquals("bar_z", response);
}

//Part of V1TestSuite.java, chosen through an Ant target or Maven execution.
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@IncludeCategory(Version1.class)
@SuiteClasses(ApiV1Test.class, ApiV2Test.class)  // *
public class V1TestSuite {}
```

You can split the test methods into as few or as many classes as you want.  Just edit the line marked with a star.  Then, run `V1TestSuite` by hand, or use appropriate ways to have it run by an Ant target or a Maven execution test step.

## Ant

```
<target name="text-version1" depends="compile-tests">
    <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${build.tests}"/>
            <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
        </classpath>

        <formatter type="plain"/>

        <test name="my.test.V1TestSuite"/>
    </junit>
</target>
```

Comment: I'm a little bit confused by that code snippet. `featureX` is part of which class?

Comment: I'm guessing where it says `@Versions("v2")` it should say `@Category({Version2.class})`. This looks great, what I don't understand is where does the value for the `String version` parameter  come from.

Comment: Cut and paste error.  Sorry. I'll edit again. In `@Category(Version1.class)`, there's no need for a string parameter.  The `@IncludeCategory(Version1.class)` tells JUnit only to run the methods marked with that category as part of that test suite.

Comment: But what value will the constructor of `ApiConnection` get as an argument? That's where I need to set the API that's being tested.

Comment: Oh, dear.  Test methods aren't supposed to take arguments in JUnit code.  You can use an `@Parameterized` test and have the constructor of the test class get a series of arguments; then the method can use `this.version`.  You can use `Theories` to turn tests off when the version is wrong.